# How to View a PDF which is inside a Webview?android

Tags: android, pdf, webview

In my web-view I have a PDF forum If user makes any changes That will be added to PDF

But Here I am Unable to View That PDF In Webview

I have Tried with `http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=`

But Its Opening My web page source Code... Only Half a part of my Webpage is PDF.. And renaming Is text-box etc..

like below

[image]

Here Pdf is showing in browser but not in my Web-view

Can any one help me I need to Show PDF and Add some changes all this in web-view please help me...

**Update**
In my webpage I am getting Pdf as a part of it not entire page as pdf is here its not working with `http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=`

If I open My Web page in that url I am getting source code of my web page... Please help

**Update 1**

Here In the above Image...... PDF is not loading in webview only web page is loading but where as a in browser its loading Please help

Answer (score 0):

The other GOOGLE-url.
Have you tried this suffix `https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=YOURURL` ?

Comment: In my webpage I am getting Pdf as a part of it not entire page as pdf is here its not working with http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=

If I open My Web page in that url I am getting source code of my web page... Please help

Answer (score 0):

Are you redirecting to drive intentionally? You have to pass the correct .pdf url

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=yoururl.pdf
```

Comment: In my webpage I am getting Pdf as a part of it not entire page as pdf is here its not working with http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=

If I open My Web page in that url I am getting source code of my web page... Please help

Comment: check mime type of the file you want to look

Comment: if entire page is not pdf, than you can directly use url to load in webview without use doc.google.drive url. But in that case web view will show other content also

Comment: yes That Image shows only web page Pdf is not loading

Comment: Have you tried using  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true) ?

Comment: Yes.... In a Web Half Pd f and Half web page I am getting So what ever I need to add in pdf I will add them in Pdf and It will show live preview.. So is there any Plugin for that to read,.

Comment: If you want to display only pdf in webview, you have explicitly get the pdf url. There is no way to extract unless you parse the web response.

Answer (score 0):

This way, you can see the PDF inside your webview.

```
String pdfURL = "http://www.expertagent.co.uk/asp/in4glestates/{16D968D6198E-4E33-88F4-8A85731CE605}/{05c36123-4df0-4d7d-811c-8b6686fdd526}/external.pdf";

webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdfURL);
```

Comment: Here In the above Image.... PDF is not loading in webview only web page is loading but where as a in browser its loading Please help

Comment: String googleDocs = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";

String pdf_url = "http://kronox.org/documentacion/Hello.Android.new.pdf";  

webView.loadUrl(googleDocs + pdf_url);

Comment: In a Webpage I have half pdf and Half fields.. If i use it with your url Its decoding All the page.. Not specific page.....